# Fourier Transform of a polynomial-like distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to proof the following result for a Fourier transform on distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n$:

*If $a\in(0,n)$, then there exist $C(n,a)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\mathcal{F(|\cdot|^{-a})} = C(n,a) |\cdot|^{a-n},
$$
where the constant $C(n,a)$  is just depending on $n$ and $a$ only.*

I tried to use the classical properties of the Fourier Transform but it does not work or does not provides me any clue.

Do you any idea how to prove it ?

Why the constant $C(n,a)$ depend just on $n$ and $a$?.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528231/find-the-fourier-transform-of-x-mu-in-mathbbrn-up-to-constant-mult